# SVProgressHud not showing

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

I want to add `SVProgressHud` to show progress. I have use method :

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please Wait..."];
```

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate`.

But I am not able to see my progress view.

Comment: stop the project and run again and check properly it showing first time when you run application or everytime not showing ? and if possible post some code what you have tried ?

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    appDelegate = self;
    self.userArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    return YES;
} this is my code i have deleted my app and again reinstall it on simulator but the problem still persist. Is it possible to call SVProgressHud Methods from AppDelegate methods.

Comment: @user2545737 Yes it is possible to call SVProgressHUD to call from appdelegate, are you dismissing the HUD andywhere in your app?

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes i m dismissing HUD by calling + (void)dismiss of SVProgressHUD

Comment: try removing the hide code and see whether the progress HUD is showing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .

and if possible set below method before execute the request

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"pleasewait.." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
```

[Download it from here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08939815145727453193)

Comment: Nothing happens by writing above code. But when i am calling above method from my ViewController class this works fine for me.

Comment: i think yes it is because of svprogresshud take the hud from view not from window.  so, first try to replace your svprogresshud.h amd .m file with attached .h and .m file . and if it's not work then use MBProgresshud. for download file check edited answer.

Comment: I have use MBProgreeHud

Comment: Good MBProgresshud is good to use. it can't conflict with another view controller. where as SVProgresshud conflict. so, you have to face problem in SVProgresshud.